# What does the combat keyword "Devastation" mean in Child of Light?

Tags: child-of-light

Occasionally, in combat, a hit that I perform on a mob will pop out the word "Devastation."  This seems to be distinct from a "Critical Strike," and doesn't always seem to kill the mob.  Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devastation simply means an overkill. In other words, it's when the amount of damage you do during a killing blow is much larger than the remaining HP on an enemy. This causes a devastation. I am not aware of any effect it has on the gameplay though.

Pretty sure it always kills a mob as it's one of the prerequisites of devastation. I've never seen it otherwise.

Comment: Just to correct partner character's can achieve "Devastation", a number of times i have had Óengus get a "Critical" and "Devastation" on one of those bird knights in the tower where the Moon was being held (where Aurora learns the truth about her sisters and of her step mother) by dealing 400+ damage on one which was wounded

Comment: @Memor-X Correct. I discovered this later but didn't remember to update my answer. Thanks for the comment